# how do I loop back to the previous functions when stop is only prompted at the

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, prompt, radix

I am facing a problem to create a loop which will loop back to the previous functions when the user does not want the program to stop (if the user wants it to stop, the program will continue with other functions).

I need to create a list of functions to do base conversion while showing the logic:

- Step1: prompt for a number
- Step2: prompt for an alphabet (b for Binary/o for Octal/h for Hexadecimal) as the base
- Step3: convert it to a string (e.g. `"108sup10 = 1101100sup2"` & `"63300268sup10 = 3C5E2A7sup16"`)
- Step4: alert the string answer in a statement (e.g: Base 10 number **63300268** is **3C5E2A7** in Hexadecimal)
- Step5: prompt to stop. If user's input is not "s", it will repeat step 1~4, else it continue to step 6.
- Step 6: alert the max and min number entered from (repeated) step1's input.

for step 1,2,3,4,6, it is mandatory to use functions.
May I know how do I code for STEP5 in order to loop back from step 1-4 when stopping is prompted? Do I need a function for this?

```
//prompt to get number
function getNumber() {
    var myNumber;
    do {
        myNumber = Number(prompt("Enter an unsigned base 10 number:")); //prompt user's input to be excecuted first
    } while (myNumber < 0) //loop will run again and again as long as the number is less than zero
    return myNumber;
}

//prompt to get base
function getBase() {
    var myBase;
    do {
        myBase = (prompt("Enter b for binary, o for octal and h for hexadecimal")); 
    } while (!(myBase == "b" || myBase == "B" || myBase  == "s" || myBase == "S"|| myBase  == "h" || myBase == "H")) //loop if the input is not b, s or h
    return myBase;
}

//converting the base to the number
function baseConversion(number, newBase) {
    var arr = [];

    if (newBase == "b" || newBase == "B") {
        newBase = 2;
    } else if (newBase == "o" || newBase == "O") {
        newBase = 8;
    }else if (newBase == "h" || newBase == "H") {
        newBase = 16;
    }

    do { //putting the each remainder at the front of the array
        arr.unshift(number%newBase); 
        number = Math.floor(number/newBase); //round down the divided answer
    } while (number>newBase-1) //loop as long as this condition holds
    arr.unshift(number); 
    return arr;
}

//function to string the arrays
function convertToString(number, base) {
    var resultString = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        var digit = results[i];
        if (digit > 9) {
            switch (digit) {
                case 10:
                    digit = 'A'
                    break;
                case 11:
                    digit = 'B'
                    break;
                case 12:
                    digit = 'C'
                    break;
                case 13:
                    digit = 'D'
                    break;
                case 14:
                    digit = 'E'
                    break;
                case 15:
                    digit = 'F'
                    break;
            }
        }
        resultString += digit;
    }

    return resultString
}

//function to alert the answer statement
function alertAnswer() {
    var statement = alert("Base 10 number:" + myNumber + "is" + base + "in" + myBase);
    return statement;
}

//function to find the maximum number in the array
function myMax(myArray) {
    var max = myArray[0];
    for (var z = 0; z < myArray.length; z++) {
        if (myArray[z] > max) {
            max = myArray[z];
        }
    }
    return max;
}

//function to find the minimum number in the array
function myMin(myArray) {
var min = myArray[0];
for (var z = 0; z < myArray.length; z++) {
    if (myArray[z] > min) {
        min = myArray[z];
    }
}
return min;
}
```

Comment: consider `hexString = yourNumber.toString(16);` instead of the long switch statement

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I'm mistaken, but is this what you're looking for?

```
var promptVar = false;

do
{
//function calls for steps 1~4
prompt();
}
while (promptVar == false)

function prompt()
{
    if (confirm('Do you want to continue to step 6?')) 
    {
        promptVar = true;
    } else {
        promptVar = false;
    }

}
```